# How to make a div same height as glyphicon contents?

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

In this simple example, the inner tag has height 14px, but the outer tag has height 20px. How can I make the container tag have the same height as its child? I tried setting the div to inline-block, but that didn't do anything.

```
<div>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: set line-height of inner tag as 20px would do it I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
div > .glyphicon {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try `block` It's more reliable in terms of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
div i:before {font-size:14px;}
```